# query for selecting data where id is max and where clause in eloquent laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to get data using eloquent in `laravel` where `id` is max and `task_id= "id"`. I've done with two queries.

Can I do with single query?

```
$id=$this->model->where('task_id','=',$task_id)->max('id');
return $this->model->where('id','=',$id)->first();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `orderBy` to order it by id in descending order.

```
return $this->model
    ->where('task_id','=',$task_id)
    ->orderBy('id','DESC')
    ->first();
```